# What is unexpected T_VARIABLE in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax-error

I get this PHP error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_VARIABLE

From this line:

```
$list[$i][$docinfo['attrs']['@groupby']] = $docinfo['attrs']['@count'];
```

Is there anything wrong with this line?

Comment: X-Ref: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them? - Unexpected T_VARIABLE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18092267) for the other common causes and context-specific fixes.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

There might be a semicolon or bracket missing a line before your pasted line.

It seems fine to me; every string is allowed as an array index.

Comment: Oh you reminded me,it's a bracket missed.Why it's called T_VARIABLE?

Comment: The error message tells you what's there (unexpected), not what's missing. And there's a variable, so it tells you exactly that.

Comment: Because the unexpected `$list` is a variable.

Comment: because php was expecting a bracket and found a variable, that's why it tells you ‘unexpected variable’

Comment: Ohh! it's a semicolon missed :-\

Comment: I have come from the future to explain why PHP specifically says `T_VARIABLE`, because I was still wondering why.

T stands for Token, and this particular token is a Variable. 

https://csveda.com/php/tokens-in-php/

Answer (score 32):

It could be some other line as well. PHP is not always that exact.

Probably you are just missing a semicolon on previous line.

**How to reproduce this error, put this in a file called `a.php`:**

```
<?php
  $a = 5
  $b = 7;        // Error happens here.
  print $b;
?>
```

**Run it:**

```
eric@dev ~ $ php a.php

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
/home/el/code/a.php on line 3
```

**Explanation:**

The PHP parser converts your program to a series of tokens.  A `T_VARIABLE` is a Token of type VARIABLE.  When the parser processes tokens, it tries to make sense of them, and throws errors if it receives a variable where none is allowed.

In the simple case above with variable `$b`, the parser tried to process this:

```
$a = 5 $b = 7;
```

The PHP parser looks at the $b after the 5 and says "that is unexpected".

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was an issue of the PHP version.

The .phar file I was using was not compatible with PHP 5.3.9. Switching interpreter to PHP 7 did fix it.