# Parse Error in unexpected T_Variable. Subscription Mail Form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

So I have this form.

Its a very simple mail/newsletter form.

```
  <form action="http://localhost/website/subscribe.php" method="POST" id="signup_form">
  <label for="email"><p id = "subText">Subscribe</p></label>
  <input type="text" name="email" size="30" class="required email txtEmail" placeholder = "Enter Email Address">
  <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" class = "goButton"/>
  </form>
```

and I have this subscribe.php file.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@email.com";
    $email_subject = "Subscription";

    function died($error)
    {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if( !isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from))
    {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0)
    {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
               'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
<!-- include your own success html here -->
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php
}
?>
```

That I found [here](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php), I just edited it a bit to fit my form. I'm really new to PHP and I'm still in the practice phase.

The error I get is

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/techstars05/www/website/subscribe.php on line 6, referer: http://localhost/website/index.html
```

I'm using sublime text 2 to edit the codes and I noticed that "if(isset($_POST['email']))"'s 'if' is of a different color from the other ifs from the subscribe.php file. Its pink while the others are violet-ish. I'm not really sure what does mean, I tried tracing the code but to my newbie eyes it looks quite fine.

TIA

Comment: I have a index.html and subscribe.php files. Every Braces are closed. How is the last Brace causing the problem?

Comment: [**The error message you get is related to this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1464941/342740), now you have to review your own code that is located at `/home/techstars05/www/website/subscribe.php` and find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    //email is set
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        //email data
        $email_from = $_POST['email'];
        $email_to = "email@email.com";
        $email_subject = "Subscription"; 
        //create body
        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();     
        if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
            echo "email sent successfully";
            exit();
        }else{
            echo "email failed to send";
        }   
    }else{
        echo "email is not valid";
    }
}else{
   echo "email is not set";
}


function clean_string($string){
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried it and it says Email sent successfully. But I do not receive any email? Is is because I'm in a localhost? LAMP/MAMP server?

Comment: Yea i know it is possible to do that from localhost but you need to do so more work. You should try it on your server