# PHP if statement && logical operator error

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

I hope this question hasn't been asked yet.

Time to time I get into the same problem while I'm coding, which is when I'm using two or more && logical operators like this:

```
if ($sCategory['sub_category_name'] == $subCat && $action == 'edit') {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

I get the error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$action' (T_VARIABLE)

As reading some of other topics, I saw that sometimes there are hidden characters which cause the problem, but I did not find any other solution to mine. I'm using Sublime Text 3 on an iMac.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you defined action variable ??

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464919/what-is-unexpected-t-variable-in-php

Comment: See the previous line ... if there is any error .

Comment: can you fetch the $sCategory['sub_category_name '] and $subcat and $action do you get the value?

Comment: post you whole script here

Comment: Yes I do get the values, how I solved it was simply changing them up: ($action == 'edit' && $sCategory['sub_category_name'] == $subCat). Don't know why but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

According to me, the array value is creating issue, so take this array value in another variable, just like this:

```
$cat_val = $sCategory['sub_category_name'];
if (($cat_val == $subCat) && ($action == "edit")) {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Please try it once.

Hope, it may be helpful to you.

Comment: That might be a possible solution, I'll check it

Comment: I checked it and it works like that. Is there any restriction in php that it == logical operator can't compare more than x variables/array values?

Comment: Ok, it depends on the server to server versions. In localhost, it will not create problem in most of the cases, but on many live servers it creates issue.